# Add two custom product type

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic

Hello i'm trying to add two custom product types, if i only add one everything works fine but when i add the other custom i get a crtic error, what im doing worng, this is the code that im using

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_bebidas' );
 
function register_bebidas() {
    class WC_Product_Demo extends WC_Product {
        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'bebidas';
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_comestibles' );
 
function register_comestibles() {
    class WC_Product_Comestibles extends WC_Product_Comestibles {
        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'bebidas';
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_bebidas' );
 
function add_bebidas( $types ){
    $types[ 'bebidas' ] = __( 'Bebidas');
    return $types;  
}
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_comestibles' );
 
function add_comestibles( $types ){
    $types[ 'comestibles' ] = __( 'Comestibles');
    return $types;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is extending itself

```
class WC_Product_Comestibles extends WC_Product_Comestibles {
```

You probably meant

```
class WC_Product_Comestibles extends WC_Product {
```

Comment: It was this! thank you very much for the help!